# "open containing folder" is taking a long time

Tags: kubuntu, kde, filemanager, dolphin

I am on Kubuntu 22.04

When in an application I select a file and do "open containing folder" (vscode files list / firefox downloads / chromium downloads) the default file manager takes 25 seconds to open.

If Dolphin is open or if I open it manually before the 25 seconds is up the folder is instantly displayed in a new tab in the Dolphin window. Even if Dolphin is not my default file manager.

run `xdg-open .` from the terminal open the current directory with the default file manager instantly.

If Thunar is installed the directory open instantly but with Thunar instead of configured file manager.

How can I solve this problem?

My specs:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-53-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
Memory: 15.5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620
```

Comment: Please include some specs.

Comment: Specs on your hardware. Model, CPU, RAM etc.

Comment: Ok, I just I added specs.

Comment: Similar issue in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. If Files has been opened at least once, even if it is currently closed, it will immediately show the selected folder. If not, it doesn't show at all (haven't had the patience to wait for 25 or more seconds to see if it will eventually open).